# Strip all HTML tags except certain ones?

Tags: c#, parsing, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a requirement where I need to strip all tags out of a large block of HTML that is tag-soup, essentially stuff like:

`<div style=""><span style=""><p style=""><div style=""><span style="">`

etc.

I need to strip them all out, *except* the `<p>` tags, but on those I need to strip out the attributes such as `style=""` and just leave them as `<p></p>`.

I am currently stripping all tags with a regex:

`public static string StripHtml(string input) => Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", string.Empty)`

Any ideas on how to do this?

I would use a customized C# library for this but I am using .Net Core on Linux so a lot of these libraries (such as AngleSharp) that require the full framework aren't going to work for me.

Comment: whatever you do, [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1132334)

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface I understand the downsides of using regex to parse HTML, that's not my go-to but the `string`s I am working with that need to be parsed are limited in size and well-formed structurally.  We're talking maybe 1k bytes max of HTML at a time with proper opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<((?!p\s).)*?>` will give you all tags except the paragraphs. So your program could delete all matches of this regex and replace the rest of the tags (all p's) with empty paragraph tags. (`<p .*?>` regex for receiving all p-tags)

Comment: Thanks, how to delete all the attributes from the remaining `<p>` tags and leave just the empty `<p>`?  I need to remove style attributes in particular.  I am terrible with regex.  I can do this in two steps if necessary.

Comment: As mentioned, you may replace replace the matchings of ``<p .*?>`` with ``<p>``.

Comment: When I added a final `.Replace` to my regex the `<p>` tags are not being cleared of attributes:  `.Replace("<p .*?> ", string.Empty);` ... like I said I'm not great with regex, I assume that space between the p and the . correct?  Any idea why this is not being wiped out?  The first regex works great, takes out all tags except the `<p>` tags as expected.

Comment: I also need it to preserve the closing `</p>` tags as I need to use this to set `InnerHtml` in Angular which needs the proper open/closing tags.

Comment: Remove all matches of ``<((?!p\b).)*?>`` instead of ``<((?!p\s).)*?>`` and the closing tags will be preserved.

Comment: That works great, the only thing that still doesn't work is using `.Replace("<p .*?> ", "<p>");` ... that regex is not matching and I am still seeing the `<p>` tables with the `style=""` attributes on them.

Comment: In the main question you wrote ``Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", string.Empty)`` so you may have forgotten to give the input string as a parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207501/discussion-between-tracer69-and-patrick).